# How to think intuitively about compact injections?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Motivation is the Sobolev inequalities, but there are more basic examples. For example, consider the inclusion

$$i: C^1([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1])$$ 
This is compact since if $\{f_n\} \subset B_1(0,1)$, then for all $x, y \in [0,1]$ we have

$$|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \leq |f_n'|_{\infty}|x - y| \leq |x - y|$$
by the mean value theorem. So $\{i(f_n)\}$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinous, hence has a convergent subsequence.

How should one think of a compact injection intuitively or informally?

Comment: This is of course difficult to answer. But I actually think that in the case of a compact operator the definition already gives a good intuition. Like in your example: You taking a bounded sequence in an infinite dimensional space and map it to another infinite dimensional space but because this map is so "nice" i.e. compact you actually are able to select a convergent subsequence. Maybe you could elaborate a bit of what kind of answer you would accept?

Comment: @hal4math It's hard for me to pinpoint exactly what I'm looking for, but I think it should depend on function spaces and not just on compact operators. I will try to elaborate a bit. It is not difficult to see that $W^{1,p}(I)$ ( $p >1$) injects compactly into $L^{\infty}(I)$ when $I$ is bounded, but not when $I$ is unbounded... obviously which injections are compact or not gets more complicated in higher dimensions. What I don't see is the bigger picture of what a compact injection vs just a continuous one is supposed to capture about the spaces.

Comment: Are you yet satisfied with the responses?

Answer (score 2):

Depending what you mean by "intuitive", the Hilbert-space case of Sobolev spaces may have more to grab onto, and having spectral expansions makes it even more explicit. E.g., on the circle, $\sum_n c_ne^{inx}$ has $L^2$ norm-squared essentially $\sum_n |c_n|^2$, and has $H^1$ norm-squared $\sum_n (1+n^2)|c_n|^2$. Thus, an orthonormal basis for $H^1$ consists essentially of $e^{inx}/\sqrt{1+n^2}$. The images of these under the inclusion to $L^2$ are still orthogonal, but they're much smaller than the unit ball. In particular, the image of the unit ball from $H^1$ is a Hilbert-cube-like thing inside $L^2$, and is easily seen to be pre-compact (e.g., by the total-boundedness criterion).

Slight edit: and, for that matter, though it may seem less physically real, describing Sobolev spaces on the spectral side, on the circle, obviously converts things to Sobolev-like spaces inside $\ell^2$...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a compact injection, you can think of bounded sets as if they were in finite dimensions, that is, you can extract converging subsequences of your bounded sequences.